# How to make individual array for Images and String ? in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, asp.net-web-api

I am working on Web_API. I got response in form of Images and String.

> Now I want to make an array for every images and String.

Here is my response:

```
JsonData={"Menu": [{"GroupMenu":"Student Info","Submenus":[{"title":"User Profile","icon":"http://192.168.0.129:85/Images/NavigationIcon/student_info.png","URL":"StudentProfile"},{"title":"View Attendence","icon":"http://192.168.0.129:85/Images/NavigationIcon/view_attendance.png","URL":"NA"},{"title":"Calender","icon":"http://192.168.0.129:85/Images/NavigationIcon/calender.png","URL":"NA"},{"title":"View TimeTable","icon":"http://192.168.0.129:85/Images/NavigationIcon/timetable.png","URL":"NA"}]},{"GroupMenu":"Transportation","Submenus":[{"title":"Map View","icon":"http://192.168.0.129:85/Images/NavigationIcon/map_view.png","URL":"GoogleMapActivity"},{"title":"Alerts & Notification","icon":"http://192.168.0.129:85/Images/NavigationIcon/alerts&notification.png","URL":"NA"},{"title":"Transportation Desk","icon":"http://192.168.0.129:85/Images/NavigationIcon/transportation_desk.png","URL":"NA"}]},{"GroupMenu":"Notification/Alerts","Submenus":[{"title":"Notification","icon":"http://192.168.0.129:85/Images/NavigationIcon/notification.png","URL":"NA"},{"title":"Principal’s Desk","icon":"http://192.168.0.129:85/Images/NavigationIcon/principal_desk.png","URL":"NA"},{"title":"Digital Diary","icon":"http://192.168.0.129:85/Images/NavigationIcon/digital_diary.png","URL":"NA"},{"title":"Assignment","icon":"http://192.168.0.129:85/Images/NavigationIcon/assignment.png","URL":"NA"}]},{"GroupMenu":"Payment Info","Submenus":[{"title":"View Bill","icon":"http://192.168.0.129:85/Images/NavigationIcon/view_bill.png","URL":"NA"},{"title":"Pay Bill","icon":"http://192.168.0.129:85/Images/NavigationIcon/pay_bill.png","URL":"NA"},{"title":"Online Payment History","icon":"http://192.168.0.129:85/Images/NavigationIcon/onlinepayment_history.png","URL":"NA"}]},{"GroupMenu":"Change Password","Submenus":[{"title":"Change Password","icon":"http://192.168.0.129:85/Images/NavigationIcon/change_password.png","URL":"NA"}]},{"GroupMenu":"Delete User","Submenus":[{"title":"Delete User","icon":"http://192.168.0.129:85/Images/NavigationIcon/delete.png","URL":"NA"}]}]}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
studinfo = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Student Info",@"calender",@"Timetable",@"View Attendance",nil];

studimageList = @[[UIImage imageNamed:@"studentinfo.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"calendrpng.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"timetable.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"viewattendance.png"]];

transinfo=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"MapView",@"Alert & Notification",@"Transportation Desk",nil];

transimageList = @[[UIImage imageNamed:@"mapview.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"alertsnotification.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"transportationdesk.png"]];

notificationinfo=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Notification",@"Principal's Desk",@"Digital Diary",@"Assignment",nil];

notificationimageList=@[[UIImage imageNamed:@"notification.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"principalsdesk.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"digitaldiary.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"assignment.png"]];

 payinfo=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"View Bill",@"Pay Bill",@"Online Payment History",nil];

 payimageList = @[[UIImage imageNamed:@"viewbill.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"paybill.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"onlinepaymenthistory.png"]];


changepassinfo=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Change Password",nil];

changepassimageList = @[[UIImage imageNamed:@"changepassword.png"]];

deleteuserinfo=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Delete User",nil];

deleteuserimageList = @[[UIImage imageNamed:@"delete.png"]];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
                                   // json can be NSDictionary *json
                                        id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

                                        // parsing data from main dict (JSON data)
                                        NSDictionary *innerDict1 = [json valueForKey:@"Menu"];

                                        // now parsing data from menu dict
                                        NSDictionary *innerDict2 = [innerDict1 valueForKey:@"Submenus"];

                                        // parsing node of Submenus dict, can pass any key inside legs
                                        NSLog(@"values: %@", [innerDict2 valueForKey:@"title"]);

                                        // getting values inside mutable array

                                        groupmenu = [innerDict1 valueForKey:@"GroupMenu"];

                                        submenu = [innerDict2 valueForKey:@"title"];

                                        icon = [innerDict2 valueForKey:@"icon"];

                                        url = [innerDict2 valueForKey:@"URL"];
                                     for(int i=0;i<groupmenu.count;i++)
                                        {
                                            switch(i)
                                         {
                                             case 0:
                                                 studinfo=submenu[i];
                                                 studimage=icon[i];

                                                 NSLog(@"studinfo= %@",studinfo);
                                                 NSLog(@"studimage %@",studimage);
                                                 break;

                                             case 1:
                                                 transinfo=submenu[i];
                                                 transimage=icon[i];

                                                 NSLog(@"transinfo= %@",transinfo);
                                                 NSLog(@"transimage %@",transimage);
                                                 break;

                                             case 2:
                                                 notificationinfo=submenu[i];
                                                 notificationimage=icon[i];

                                                NSLog(@"notificationinfo= %@",notificationinfo);
                                                NSLog(@"notificationimage= %@",notificationimage);
                                                 break;
                                             case 3:
                                                 paymentinfo=submenu[i];
                                                 paymentimage =icon[i];

                                                 NSLog(@"paymentinfo= %@",paymentinfo);
                                                 NSLog(@" paymentimage = %@",paymentimage );
                                                 break;
                                             case 4:
                                                 changepass=submenu[i];
                                                 changepassimage=icon[i];

                                                 NSLog(@"changepass= %@",changepass);
                                                 NSLog(@"changepassimage= %@",changepassimage);
                                                 break;
                                             case 5:
                                                 delete=submenu[i];
                                                 deleteimage= icon[i];

                                                 NSLog(@"deleteimage= %@",deleteimage);
                                                 break;
                                         }
                                    }
```

Comment: just remind cases are not static all the time, anyway +1.

Comment: yeah.. Actually My project is Dynamic... btw Thanks @vaibhav

Answer (score 0):

JsonData is a dictionary. So, you need to get the keys out of it which is an array containing different sets of dictionaries. Iterate over different keys to setup your lists.

This should get you started:

```
for(int i = 0; i < ((NSArray*)[jsonData valueForKey:@"Menu"]).count; i++){
    NSArray *subMenu = [[(NSArray*)[jsonData valueForKey:@"Menu"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Submenus"];
    for(int k = 0; k < subMenu.count; k++){
        [studimageList addObject:([[[[(NSArray*)[jsonData valueForKey:@"Menu"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Submenus"] objectAtIndex:k] valueForKey:@"icon"])];
    }

    [transinfo addObject:([[(NSArray*)[jsonData valueForKey:@"Menu"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"GroupMenu"])];
        .
        .
        .
    }
```

Comment: its not working  this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Menu.'

Comment: I would have probably down-voted it because it's very untidy, likely to crash and, if scaled up, make maintenance of the code pretty much impossible - imho

Comment: Fair enough the idea was to give OP a starting point to comprehend json data

Comment: Which is fine, but i've fallen into that trap before where the code does work and you never get around to putting something in more robust or scalable and you end up knee deep of trouble when you come back to it in 2 years time. Bad times..

Answer (score 0):

If `JSONData` is a string, then you will need to create an `NSData*` object to deserialise it to an `NSDictionary*`.
*The way that I would do it*, is create a custom object that derives from `NSObject*` where the initialiser takes the JSONData as a parameter.
Have the object have public read-only parameters, where the initialisation set them. Assuming it is an NSDictionary...

```
-(instancetype)initWithJsonData:(NSDictionary*)jsonData{
    if(self=[super init]){
        _subMenu = jsonData[@"Menu"];

        _menuImage = //load image from URL async
    }
   return self;
}
```

Ignore the crudity of this sudo code, but hopefully you get the idea. Then you will be able to handle this object correctly and easily in your tables or anywhere else, where you will be able to then just go

```
CustomObject * object = [[CustomObject alloc]initWithJsonData:jsonData];  
title = object.menuTitle;
```

Of course, if you are downloading images async (which you should be) then make sure to try calling `object.image` straight away or it will still be `nil`.
This may be overkill for one or two items, but it saves a lot of faff passing around objects between controllers.
I assume you are handling the API as the ip addresses are local. I would suggest that for URLs you either give absolute addresses, or set a base URL and just pass around relative addresses to retrieve data from. Also, if something is 'NA' (I assume is non-applicable) that you nil or null the field rather than putting in an 'NA' string, which you are going to have to manually parse.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I would even go as far as to create another sub object for you 'groupMenu' objects. That way you can have an array of `GroupMenu` items that you can iterate over when populating your UITableView

Comment: Also. If you need to visualise how to structure your data models, try pasting your json data into something like http://jsonprettyprint.com/ to give you a good idea